# Ipod stops Playing while recording Audio

Tags: iphone, ios5

Recording the audio and playing the iPod at the same time, but iPod stops playing,while recording audio in iPhone application. Please help

Comment: can you post some your code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, just tested it out on my iPhone 4, 5.0.1. It's probably to avoid possible interference between the output music and the mic, since, to my knowledge, the microphone and the speakers are right next to each other.